# How i can make this layout (buttons with text & icons)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-button

I try to achieve something like this:

[image]

My code so far is :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btemail"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/mail"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btcharts"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btemail"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btemail"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/chart"
            android:drawablePadding="-35dp"
            android:text="Charts"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bthistory"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btemail"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btemail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btemail"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/list"
            android:text="History"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btimport"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bthistory"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btcharts"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/add"
            android:text="New Measurement"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My view is this:

[image]

Can this be done with relative view only or should i use gridview?

If i set  android:layout_height="130dp" but the icons has different size for diffrent screens "50x50 66x66 98x98 130x130".Will be a problem for diffrent screens?
Is there a way to achieve it dynamically??

How to put the icon center vertical and horizontal of the chart button????Because now it is a little more up of the center..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use **`RelativeLayout`** for text and background and buttons place into **`TableLayout`** or **`GridLayout`**(with appropriate margins) that will be nested in it's parent - **`RelativeLayout`**.

Answer (score 1):

The dp or dip metric is the number of pixels at density 160 or mdpi, so you set the size on your layout folder as the pixels in mdpi and scale the other sizes as the table below:

- xhdpi: 2.0
- hdpi: 1.5
- mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
- ldpi: 0.75

For more info see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html)

Edit: I believe the best way to do this layout is to have all the buttons in a linear layout and have a relative layout as root and do the aligning of the linear layout by the gravity or something like that.

My example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btcharts"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:drawablePadding="-35dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/chart"
            android:text="Charts"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btimport"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/add"
            android:text="New Measurement"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btemail"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/mail"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bthistory"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/list"
            android:text="History"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know that it's all aligned because I don't have your drawables here, but I can think you can improve from this, also your "charts" button is different because it has a transparent background.

Comment: i have all the necesery icons for different sizes..

I just want to accomplish the 2x2 buttons grid like the picture...

Comment: I misunderstand your question then, see the edit with the code that I would do in your case.